My stats on Minecraft Realms are not updating
I logged back a couple of months ago on my friend's Realm after a long time and discovered this new feature called Realms Stories.
The game used to crash a lot, so I just waited for an eventual update to fix the issue... which happened, and now I can access my profile.
My problem is that every friend of mine has a stats page showing stuff like hours played, blocks destroyed, creatures defeated... except me. My stats are all zeros.
I suppose this is due to the fact that I'm the only one playing from PS4, and maybe there's a sort of conflict with my Microsoft account.
Is there a way to fix this? I know it's not a big deal, but I really like to track this kind of useless info.

If you can see your friend's stats updating, can they see yours? Also, are your friends having this issue too? Maybe there is a bug in the new Realms update that prevents a user from seeing their updated stats.

"I really like to track this kind of useless info." I get that. There is something really satisfying about watching those numbers go up.

@Alex no they don't see my stats either, and none of my friends (from other platforms) are experiencing this bug.

Oh weird. Then your probably on the right track about the PS4 edition conflict with your account. Maybe the PS4 isn't updating to the server correctly, too.
Do you have any other editions of Minecraft that can connect to the realms server? If so, see if the issue applies there.

@Alex sadly no, I only own PS Vita, PS3 and PS4 edition

@pinkerman Okay. I have a weird idea. Try signing in to your account on a friends device for a very brief amount of time, go onto the server, do a few things to get the counters up, and check if the issue happens on that device, too. If the numbers go up, it's the PS4 edition. If it doesn't, then this is a weird bug in the server that just doesn't like your account's name. Then send a bug report to whichever company that can fix the issue. I could be wrong about all of that, but those are my top guesses at the moment. Oh, Don't forget to log your friend's device out of your account, of course.

@Alex well this may require a while, because I rarely visit them, we don't live close to each others.. but this sounds like a good idea

Sounds good. And the bright side is if you do give it a go, and the server seems to be the problem, we'll know that knightsGaming's answer is correct. It's a win win.

This has happened to me as well. I found that uninstalling and reinstalling the game can help, but this doesn't consistently fix the issue. It is most likely a visual glitch or a lag in the client side or server. If the problem persists, report it to the Minecraft bug website.

Is there an already open issue about this bug?
